# The way we authenticate users no longer works, gives authentication error

Tags: php, authentication, ssl, gmail

I have this PHP function:

```
public static function smtpmailer($to, $from, $from_name, $subject, $body) { 
    $mail = new PHPMailer();  // create a new object
    $mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;  // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;  // authentication enabled
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for GMail
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    $mail->Port = 465; 
    $mail->Username = "someemail@gmail.com";  
    $mail->Password = "somepassword";           
    $mail->SetFrom($from, $from_name);
    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->Body = $body;
    if (is_string($to)) {
        $to = array($to);
    }
    foreach ($to as $t) {
        $mail->AddAddress($t);
    }
    if(!$mail->Send()) {
        $error = 'Mail error: '.$mail->ErrorInfo; 
        return false;
    } else {
        $error = 'Message sent!';
        return true;
    }
}
```

This was successfully used before, but now it gives me an error I do not understand:

> string(1553) "**Warning** [2] stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL
>   operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
>   error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate
>   verify failed

Some authentication does not pass, but both the username and password is correct. This was used from URL1 successfully before and I copied this code to another site, having URL2. However, the error mentioned above occurred. When I tried this at URL1, to find out whether this is a settings problem in my gmail account used for email verification, I encountered the same error. My question is: what should I fix and how in order to be able to successfully send an authentication email in terms of settings of the gmail account and the code I've shown above?

EDIT

Differences between this question and the one marked as the on this being duplicate with:

- this is a question involving PHP code, that question is about Pythonic problems
- this question is very specific about gmail usage and the desire of comply to google smtp terms and policies
- the other question is about file downloading, this one is about sending an email from a given gmail address
- the other question is about a popup with certificates in the browser, things here happen on server-side

Comment: @kabanus I think this is not a duplicate, since this is about meeting gmail's requirements in a way which previously worked, but due to at least a change unkown to me fails to work now.

Comment: Are you sure it's not a gmail certificate you previously had or a change of hostname?

Comment: @kabanus for URL2 I have a different hostname. But for URL1, I am using a certificate which was created earlier and worked back then. I have tested with URL1 as well to rule out the possibility of problems due to wrong certificate and/or hostname change.

Comment: @kabanus I have upgraded PHPMailer and not I receive the following error: Mail error: SMTP connect() failed.

Comment: I need to switch to tls on 587 from ssl on 465 according to https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/issues/149. But the connection is still unsuccessful

Comment: I understand now - this was changed a while ago. You might also need to allow "less secure apps" to connect to Gmail. I can't remember off the top of my head all you have to do, but Google may be blocking you on purpose. I suggest searching/posting on the Google forums.

Comment: @kabanus I have already done that. I am trying to switch to the API of gmail, hoping to have better success.

Comment: @kabanus I have tried to solve this using google API, but got a zend_mm_heap corrupted error. I do not understand this. I would simply like to send an email from a gmail account I own. This worked previously. I am puzzled about the causes of the difficulties I have.

Comment: I highly recommend the Google forums - when I had trouble with Mutt they solved it for me.

Comment: @kabanus I have been reading them for hours, without luck. However, if I switched to PHP 5.4.3, it works. Using PHP 5.6.26 it does not work. It is either a version or a settings problem.

Comment: @kabanus after a long session of torture I was able to make this work, check out my answer for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The steps for the solution were as follows:

1. Make sure that the gmail account allows access from the app. You can do this by going to the settings of the account and [Let Less Secure apps use your account](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en),
2. Make sure that PHPMailer corresponds to the PHP version in use
3. We need the following settings:

`$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for GMail
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    $mail->Port = 587;`

4. Also, make sure we set the SMTPOptions:

   ```
   $mail->SMTPOptions = array(
   'ssl' => array(
           'verify_peer' => false,
           'verify_peer_name' => false,
           'allow_self_signed' => true
       )
   );
   ```

Comment: Nice, glad to see you got it.